# Shopware 6 shop down - Error 500 after activating a plugin. What to do?

Tags: shopware6

i tried to activate a plugin and now i get the following errors, i cant login to the backend. I am not an expert:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "admin_worker" (in "/www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/config/packages/shopware.yaml"). Looked for namespace "admin_worker", found ""framework", "monolog", "sensio_framework_extra", "twig", "web_profiler", "debug", "enqueue", "enqueue_adapter", "shopware", "storefront", "elasticsearch", "frosh_tools"" in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/config/packages/shopware.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/config/packages/shopware.yaml").
Exceptions 2Stack Traces 2
Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\
LoaderLoadException
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php (line 174)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php -> doImport (line 98)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/FileLoader.php -> import (line 66)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/GlobFileLoader.php -> import (line 27)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php -> load (line 40)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php -> load (line 268)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php -> configureContainer (line 171)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/ClosureLoader.php -> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\{closure} (line 39)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php -> load (line 40)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php -> load (line 196)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php -> registerContainerConfiguration (line 649)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php -> buildContainer (line 545)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php -> initializeContainer (line 191)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/shopware/core/HttpKernel.php -> boot (line 126)
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/vendor/shopware/core/HttpKernel.php -> doHandle (line 79)
HttpKernel->handle(object(Request))
in /www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/public/index.php (line 74)
if ($_SERVER['COMPOSER_PLUGIN_LOADER'] ?? $_SERVER['DISABLE_EXTENSIONS'] ?? false) {    $kernel->setPluginLoader(new \Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\KernelPluginLoader\ComposerPluginLoader($classLoader));}$result = $kernel->handle($request);$result->getResponse()->send();$kernel->terminate($result->getRequest(), $result->getResponse());
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\
InvalidArgumentException
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "admin_worker" (in "/www/htdocs/w016e110/shopware-boxen-werk.de/config/packages/shopware.yaml"). Looked for namespace "admin_worker", found ""framework", "monolog", "sensio_framework_extra", "twig", "web_profiler", "debug", "enqueue", "enqueue_adapter", "shopware", "storefront", "elasticsearch", "frosh_tools"".
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the config in `config/packages/shopware.yaml` is wrong. Just uncomment it. Your IDE should normally show the error as the config has an JSON schema. https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/config-schema.json

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you used the property admin_worker as main node but should be child node of shopware like this.

```
# config/packages/shopware.yaml
shopware:
    admin_worker:
        enable_admin_worker: false
```